# How to store output of this for each loop in comma separated string?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have two xmls, User.xml and UIDL Rules.xml
**user.xml** is like this..

```
<UI-defination>
 <class name="User">
 <list_view>
 <members>
  <member name="code"/>
  <member name="creationTS"/>
  <member name="creator"/>
  <member name="displayName"/>
  <member name="emailAddress"/>
  <member name="id"/>
  <member name="loginId"/>
  <member name="password"/>
  <member name="remarks"/>
  <member name="status"/>
 </members>
</list_view>
</class>
</UI-defination>
```

My **UIDL Rules.xml** contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<UI-defination>
<class name="Role">
    <list_view multiselect="true">
        <members>
            <member name="loginId" sequence="4" />
            <member name="code" sequence="1" />
            <member name="status" sequence="6"/>
        </members>
        <exclude>
            <members>
                <member name="id"/>
                <member name="creator"/>
            </members>
        </exclude>
    </list_view>
  </class>
</UI-defination>
```

**My xslt code is**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org       2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com">
<xsl:variable name="uiRules"
    select="document('UIDL Rules.xml')" />
<xsl:variable name="reserved-members">
    <xsl:for-each
        select="$uiRules//UI-defination/class/list_view/members/member[@sequence]">
        <xsl:sort select="@sequence" data-type="number" order="ascending" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:key name="member" match="list_view/members/member" use="@name" />
<xsl:variable name="exclude"
    select="key('member', $uiRules//exclude/members/member/@name)" />
<xsl:variable name="exclude1"
    select="key('member', $uiRules//UI-defination/class/list_view/members/member[@sequence]/@name)" />
<xsl:variable name="ordinary-members"
    select="//list_view/members/member except $exclude" />
<xsl:variable name="ordinary-members1" select="$ordinary-members except $exclude1" />   
<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="$reserved-members/member">
            <xsl:variable name="previous-place">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="position()>1">
                        <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::member[1]/@sequence" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="0" />
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
 <xsl:variable name="gap-size" select="@sequence - $previous-place - 1"/>
 <xsl:variable name="gap-start" select="$previous-place - count(preceding-sibling::member) + 1"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$ordinary-members1[$gap-start &lt;= position() and position() &lt; $gap-start + $gap-size]">                  
                <xsl:variable name="currentMember" select="@name" />
                    <xsl:value-of select="$currentMember" />
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:variable name="currentMember" select="@name" />
                <xsl:value-of select="$currentMember" />

            <!-- output remaining ordinary members -->
            <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
                <xsl:for-each
                    select="$ordinary-members1[position() >= $gap-start + $gap-size]">
                    <xsl:variable name="currentMember" select="@name" />
                        <xsl:value-of select="$currentMember"/>                     
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My requirement is list out member from **user.xml** minus exclude member from **UIDL Rule.xml** and arrange remaining members as per their **sequence** attribute. This above code works fine but i have to use this logic at 15 different places, so it will be great if i put output in a variable whose value will be member separated by comma.
Any suggestions ?

```
Desired output sequence should look like this
1>code
2>creationTS
3>displayName
4>loginId
5>emailAddress
6>status
7>password
8>remarks
```

Comment: Consider to post working code, yours does not compile, as `$gap-start` is not defined, as `<xsl:value-of select="$currentMember" >` is not closed. Generally with XSLT if you want to reuse code then you can write a template or in XSLT 2.0 also a function and return a value, for instance in XSLT 2.0 a sequence of strings seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: @MarcusRickert, yes, I have, though I am not 100% certain whether I interpreted the question correctly, see below.

Comment: @Abel I don't know why but I couldn't update my edited question. I will try again to update in question shortly.

Comment: Go ahead, just click the "Edit" button below the question to do so.

Comment: @Abel fixed the code. Also written what output I am expecting.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Have you taken some time to look at my answer? Because the output you show here is exactly what I output, except that the order in which I output it is with @sequence first, then the rest alphabetical, but you can just remove the sorting. Of course, I created elemements, not just text, but it is trivial to apply templates to the result set to get the values as text, if that is what you want. I'm not sure how your output relates to "comma separated string" in your question title, but anyway, how you format it is irrelevant, you can do that on the result any way you like.

Comment: @Abel Yes, I checked your answer. It first take 'sequence' element and then get non-@sequence element.
But I wanted it in this format. 
"code, creationTS, displayName, loginId, emailAddress, status, password, remarks"
And really appreciate your help. Thanks again.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I don't know what you are asking. In your OQ you say "and arrange the remaining members as per their sequence attribute". Which is what I did in my answer. If you don't want this ordering, just remove it. If you want it alphabetically, apply sort on the value, if you don't want to sort it, remove the sort. You should have enough pointers to tweak it to your needs, if not, please make clear what particular issue you are still facing.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a week old and did not receive renewed attention from the OP, but I am going to give it a go anyway.

I tried your code, but as Martin Honnen already pointed out, it is broken. Tags are not properly closed and variables are missing. Also, it contains a lot more information that was not covered in the post, so even after I added the variables and tried to use, it didn't give the results that you described in your post.

So, because the requirements were so basic, I thought to myself, let's give it a try. Requirements as I understood them were:
- Take all members from `user.xml`
- Remove the members that have the same name in the `exclude` section in `UIDL Rule.xml` (which is not a valid URI, so I removed the space).
- Order the members based on the value in the corresponding `sequence` attribute in the rule file.

This is what I came up with and it does exactly what you said:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="uiRules" select="document('UIDLRules.xml')" />

    <xsl:variable name="excl" select="$uiRules/*/*/*/exclude/members/member/data(@name)" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="unsorted" as="element()*">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:for-each select="$unsorted">
            <xsl:sort select="@sequence" order="descending" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" />

    <xsl:template match="member[not(@name = $excl)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@name" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@name">
        <xsl:copy />
        <xsl:copy-of select="$uiRules/*/*/*/members/member[@name = current()]/@sequence" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using your input, this is the output (i.e., `id` and `creator` are filtered out, and the order is based on `sequence` attribute).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<member name="status" sequence="6"/>
<member name="loginId" sequence="4"/>
<member name="code" sequence="1"/>
<member name="creationTS"/>
<member name="displayName"/>
<member name="emailAddress"/>
<member name="password"/>
<member name="remarks"/>
```

The trick I used is simple: just augment the original input `member` elements with the extra attribute from the rules xml file and then do a sort.

*Your question* was how to capture that in a variable (well, you speak of "*this* for-each loop, but you have multiples of them and I have only one in my solution above).

Also, since you have already so many variables in your code, I am not certain whether I understand your question correctly. But to cut to the chase, you can wrap either the `xsl:for-each` in a variable, this will allow you reuse on a local level, or you can wrap the whole processing in a variable.

I.e., you could do this to create a global variable that contains a sorted list of members:

```
<!-- global variable for re-use -->
<xsl:variable name="sorted">
    <xsl:variable name="unsorted" as="element()*">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="$unsorted">
        <xsl:sort select="@sequence" order="descending" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- the central match is now replaced by a simple copy -->
    <xsl:copy-of select="$sorted" />
</xsl:template>
```

This works, because the global context item is the same as the initial context item for the initial mode. In other words, you can reference the original input document by just applying templates to it. The output, after the above changes, is unchanged, but you can re-use the variable as much as you want.

Note that known XSLT 2.0 processors, such as [Exselt](http://exselt.net) (disclaimer, I am a developer of this), [Saxon](http://saxonica.com) or the one from [Altova](http://altova.com) cache global variables, so the whole processing of the variable will only take place once.

Comment: You could also use `xsl:perform-sort` instead of the `xsl:for-each`. I'm not sure how that compares efficiency wise, but it would save one line of code ;-)

Comment: @DanielHaley: you're absolutely right, I just never think of `xsl:perform-sort`, I should add it on my radar ;).